# Geometric intuition for graphing a part of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, graphing-functions

Trying to explain to a non-mathematician the meaning of complex numbers, I came across a nice geometric intuition for "seeing" the complex zeros of a function. Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a function. Then
\begin{equation}
f(x+iy) = A(x,y) + iB(x,y)
\end{equation}
The problem is that we cannot graph $f$ because we have a 3-dimensional constrained visual understanding. But if we consider the locus $\Gamma$ of points on the plane such that $B(x,y)=0$, we can actually plot a graph with the information about the zeros of $f$. On $\Gamma$ the function takes only real values so we can plot $f$ as a height map over $\Gamma$ in $3D$ space.

For example, if $f(x+iy)=(x+iy)^2$, we have that
\begin{equation}
f(x+iy) = x^2-y^2 + 2ixy
\end{equation}
and setting $2xy=0$ gives us the union of the x-axis and the y-axis. Plotting $f$ over this set gives the union of two parametric curves:
\begin{equation}
(t,0,t^2)\qquad\text{and}\qquad (0,t,-t^2)
\end{equation}
If we now consider the function $f(x+iy)=(x+iy)^2 + c$ we can see that what the parameter $c$ does is to shift these parametric curves up and down along the $z$-axis. The intersection of these curves with the $z=0$ plane shows how the zeros of the function move around in a very visual way.

In short, setting the imaginary part of a complex function equal to zero defines the locus of points on $\mathbb{C}$ or on the plane where the function takes only real values, letting us see that part of the function as a height map.

Question: does this geometric locus have a name? Is it used in some way somewhere?

Comment: [+1] Funny! Unfortunately not bijective. Never seen it before...

Comment: With $f(z)=z^3$ it's even nicer. What is it that's not bijective?

Comment: You might want to check out the domain coloring method. It uses hue to indicate the argument of the complex value and brightness for the magnitude. For example, [here](http://imgur.com/a/ZVDza) is the plot of the function you discussed. The zeroes are very clear from this diagram.

Comment: By "not bijectiv"e I meant that from a given reprentation you cannot retrieve a unique function $Z=f(z)$.

Comment: ah, that's really unfortunate

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay yes, I am aware of the domain coloring method but I find that this way of seeing the real part of $f$ gives more insight...to me, at least

Answer (score 1):

[Deeparaj Bhat](http://www.cmi.ac.in/people/student-profile.php?id=deeparaj) gave me the following idea:

Because all such values which essentially have no imaginary part are real, we can consider them to be in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, what we are looking for is the pre-image of $\mathbb{R}$ and can be denoted $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ with a slight abuse of notation.

Then, you could think of your plot as the plot of $|f(.)|$ restricted to $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Yes, but I guess I'm plotting just $f$, not $|f|$

Comment: @marcotrevi sure, but they are the same thing when the map is restricted to this domain.

Comment: no, it's not true- take $f(x)=x^3$. Then $|f|$ is always non negative while $f(-2)=-8$...